# WiFi lock doesn't work, how to prevent wifi power save?

Tags: android, wifi, wifimanager, android-wake-lock

I had done an app that transform the phone into a webcam and use the phone connection to send image to internet web space.

I'm using ad activity that set an Alarm Manager to execute a Service every 5 or 15 minutes.
To perform the entire execution of the Service I do a wake lock, but it's dropped when service finisched.

All this works perfect with mobile connection but doesn't do the same with wifi.

I had set in wifi options th policy "NEVER" for wifi sleep.
But after a time (not always the same) the phone seems to go on power save mode: wifi icon is yet on status bar but the phone isn't able to connect. Even is i use browser...so I must disconnect and manually reconnect. 
The message in the logcat: `notify conn break (IOEx), close connection`
Even with phone plugged on power!!!

why? (1)

Doing experiment with another app formed by an activity that start a service always running with a wake lock. So i have added the wifi lock to be sure of connectivity, but also this method sometimes runs and some other not. Always the same `notify conn break (IOEx), close connection` why? (2)

The last experiment is derived from the first app (alarm manager) and to be sure that the wifi doesn't go on sleep/power save mode (witch one??) i have turn the phone in airplane mode after the execution of the code and i turn it off (connection on) when the cycle begin. This work ok for two days, but after only sometimes it's work (each hour or two instead each 5 minutes, or sometimes doesn't work for an entire day and then restart without any reason..). So, why airplane mode sometimes doesn't re-establish the prewious wifi connection? (and some other times it does?) (3)

The phone is a Samsung Galaxy ACE with originale 2.2 and is ALWAYS plugged to charge.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147203/wifi-sleeps-even-with-lock

Answer (score 5):

To keep device from entering 'power save mode', try to use wifi lock of type [WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF)
It's not public available until android 3.1.
but you can still use it by hard-coding, the value of WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF is 3(int).
I tried it on a pre-3.1 device. It works like a charm! good luck!