# Android - How to wake up wifi?

Tags: android, wifi, sleep, wakelock, wakeup

I have an app that sends data every 5 min, i saw that wifi after some time goes sleep and stop working.

I found one solution that is use a WakeLock `SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK`.
The thing is:  i can't have my screen waking (even dimmed) in this process. `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` doesn't work in this case (to wake up wifi).

There is another solution for this problem?

**UPDATE:**

I'm using this topic method to lock wifi, and isn't work either:
[Wifi sleeps, even with Lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147203/wifi-sleeps-even-with-lock)

There is something wrong?

Comment: I've noticed this happen on some devices as well. The solution that I found (granted I didn't really dig) was not programmatic, I had to manually switch off and then on the wifi radio with a toggle widget.

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19968708/281545. Is that what you want ? And by the way if both resist are the same how about unifying your accounts ? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `WifiManager.WifiLock`? Creating and holding a wifiLock is the way your suppose to keep your radio awake enough to send.

Also check: Just prior to sending your message, print out what ConnectivityManager thinks about your TYPE_WIFI connection. Does the ConnectivityManager think all is well with your wifi?

Comment: Also, if your using Multicast, there's a different lock for that.

Comment: I can't do that. To lock my wifi connection i have to keep her always waked, and this can't be done. (battery issues)  Just create a wifi lock every 5 min will not wake up wifi.  Thanks anyway!