# Different possibilites for keeping wifi radio turned on?

Tags: android, wifi, wakelock

I have been reading as much as I can regarding the developer docs for the Android SDK about the following:

- Wifi wakelock
- WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF
- Wifi sleep policy

They all make sense in their own context but I can't see the "big picture" so to speak.

1. I guess that both the wifi wakelock and the WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF setting overrides the user sleep policy. Is that right?
2. If I have the sleep policy on "Never", and I just make experimental APK:s for myself which is downloading stuff in the background via wifi, I guess I don't need the wifi wake lock nor the WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF?
3. The [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147203/wifi-sleeps-even-with-lock) I have seen using a wifi wake lock has also acquired a power wake lock. Is there any occasion where I only want to acquire the wifi lock but not the power lock?

Answer (score 0):

1. If the device goes into a deep sleep and shuts down wi-fi radio, the wi-fi lock will wake it back up when the lock is acquired.  Correct, this is regardless of your wi-fi policy.
2. I think you have it backwards- the policy question says "Keep Wi-Fi on during sleep" so if you want to avoid the need for wifi locks, you would choose the "Always" option value.  I'd like to see a battery consumption analysis of Wi-Fi stay connected, versus sporadic 4G in deep sleep...
3. I have never needed or used a power wake lock.  Just system and wifi, and everything has worked fine for me to perform the functions desired.