# Lose data [ 3G / WIFI ] connectivity when phone goes to sleep mode

Tags: android, wifi, sip, 3g

I am using Samsung Galaxy with ICS.

I am developing a SIP client.  the client loses connection with the server once the phone goes in sleep mode.  Have tried the "WIFI Lock" app from android market and have tried setting WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_NEVER but no success so far.  Have anybody solved this kind of connectivity issue programatically in the past?  I need to have internet connectivity on.  Bet it mobile data / WIFI because I cannot afford to lose the connection with the server.

Comment: I know this is really old, but did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: It was not an android issue.  There was one sleep in one of our thread which was causing the the LOCK to be released.  I vaguely remember the exact solution though.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that in your manifest you have the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

It will be used to set the Wi-Fi sleep policy to never sleep while connected to a trusted network.

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Then you only need to do this:

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY, 
            Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_NEVER);
```

Comment: did you have the permission in your manifest? I'm saying this because i've tested this code and its working...

Comment: What is the result of the setting when you do this: `android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY, Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_DEFAULT)`

Comment: There is no error.  The android.provider.Settings.System.getInt returns true and app behaves as it was before.  Connectivity lost after phone sleeps.

Comment: returns true? it should return an integer... The method above is `getInt` not `putInt`.  It should return what is setting defined.

Comment: Apologies, overlooked the get part.  I called it after setInt and the value returned is 2.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13946/discussion-between-btr-naidu-and-filipe-batista)

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the Wifi settings, pressing the menu button and selecting advanced. There you'll find an item to manage the wifi sleep policy.

Also, if the WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_NEVER is not working, check out if you have permission for that on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html. I dunno which one you should use, maybe `WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS`, `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE`, `CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE`, `CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE` or `CHANGE_WIFI_STATE`.

Comment: In Wifi settings, the sleep policy is already set to NEVER.

I have tried WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_NEVER with WRITE_SETTINGS & WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS and printed the return of Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY, 
            Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_NEVER); which returns true.  Not sure if the return has any significance here.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5422400/62921) apparently there are numerous bugs about that on the Android Bug Tracker which might occurs even with Locks and permissions.

---

In my case, I manage to make the Lock work with all the device I can test on. Not sure how you tried to implement it, so here is a version I found over internet (Sorry if I cannot find back the author).

*Note: my version may slightly differs with the Java version since I am using Xamarin Android in C#, but the logic should remain the same.*

First you have to add the permission for locking the Wifi

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Second you have to get the wifiManager

```
wifiManager = (WifiManager) GetSystemService(WifiService);
```

Then you must write code to aquire and release the lock at the proper time.

```
private void AquireWifiLock() 
{
    if (wifiLock == null) 
    {
        wifiLock = wifiManager.CreateWifiLock(WifiMode.Full, "aTagForYourLock");
        wifiLock .Acquire();
    }
}


private void ReleaseWifiLock() 
{
    if (wifiLock == null) 
    {
        return;
    }

    wifiLock .Release();
    wifiLock = null;
}
```